# show the Taylor expansion converge in a given condition

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

[image: Taylor]

By applying the given condition, I obtain the following. But then what I can do to show the error tends to zero.

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions let you test straightforwardly the absolute convergence of the series: if $|x-x_0|<\varrho$, then choose $\delta>0$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta<\varrho$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{|f^{(k)}(x_0)|}{k!}\,|x-x_0|^k\leq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac\delta\varrho\right)^k<\infty,
$$
since $\delta/\varrho<1$.